# How do I animate a smooth texture animation?

Tags: animation

I am following the Youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-h6JLUctbYs and I am stuck at trying to animate my texture. Every time I try to play the animation, the texture jumps to different parts of the object, and not in a smooth flowing pattern. I tried many things to fix  this but can't find a solution. All help is appreciated!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, please [add images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/185493/edit) or [a gif](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) that show  *your* results rather than only a link to a 15 min vid. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I have added pictures of my animation and the nodes I used. As you can see there is a big jump in the texture from the first picture to the second one.

Comment: Hello, You are trying to animate the "Location" when you want to be animating the "Rotation" of the mapping node. The Mapping node setup has changed, but the 3 panels for transforms stayed the same. Look more closely at around 11:46

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! I can't believe I didn't try that out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't animate the "Location," you want to be animating the "Rotation" of the mapping node.

Comment: don't forget to mark your answer as accepted later, check [tour]